# Store generic method + arg type + return type inside list to call it later

Tags: c#, types, casting, runtime

I'm trying to archive something like a "Register Method for a certain Event" with different Argument types and Return Types, so far my plan worked out with generics.

After calling the RegisterMethod function I need to store the given "method" argument inside a List including its Input Type and Output Type. For later use I want to invoke the given method with the registered Types.

The problem I do have now is the following: After ProcessIncomingRequest is called on the server, I need to Deserialize the byte[] data to the given Type i defined in the RegisterMethod method aswell as the return Type in order to respond to the Client. But I don't know how to Cast these types in the code.

```
struct MethodData
{
    public string Name;
    public System.Reflection.MethodInfo MethodInfo;
    public Type ReturnType;
    public Type ArgumentType;
}

class NetworkServer
{
    List<MethodData> list = new List<MethodData>();
    public void RegisterMethod<In, Out>(string name, Func<NetworkClient, In, Out> method)
    {
        list.Add(new MethodData()
        {
            MethodInfo = method.Method,
            Name = name,
            ReturnType = typeof(Out),
            ArgumentType = typeof(In)
        });

        // Store the method including 
        // it the return type
        // In theory I want to add them to a List/Dictionary
        // and re-use the method + types in the
        // ProcessIncomingRequest method.
    }

    public void RegisterMethod<In>(string name, Action<NetworkClient, In> method)
    {
        list.Add(new MethodData()
        {
            MethodInfo = method.Method,
            Name = name,
            ArgumentType = typeof(In),
        });
        // Same as above, this method doesn't return anything. Its just a call and forget
    }

    public static void ProcessIncomingRequest(NetworkClient cl, string name, byte[] data)
    {
        var method = list.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(name));

        if(method != NULL)
        {
            var finalData = Serializer<Tin>(data);
            // Tin = it.ArgumentType
            // Tout = it.ReturnType
            // This is exactly what I would need to archive

            var retn = it.MethodInfo.Invoke(null, new[] { cl, finalData });
            if(retn != NULL && it.ReturnType != NULL)
                cl.Send<Tout>(retn);
        }

        // name represents the method name in the List
        // data represents represents the parameter values
        // The generic "Tin" and "Tout is the problem here
    }
}


static void main()
{
    NetworkServer server = new NetworkServer(9000);
    server.RegisterMethod<int, bool>("CheckValue", CheckValue);
    server.RegisterMethod<string>("Log", NotifyLogger);
    server.Start();
}


// Execute method with received data and return result to client
static bool CheckValue(NetworkClient cl, int value)
{
    return value >= 10;
}


// Execute data without the need of any return
static void NotifyLogger(NetworkClient cl, string logger)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Incoming Logger request : {logger}");
    MyLogger.Write($"[SERVER] {logger}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to [call a method that takes a generic type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method) with a type-object you need to use reflection.

Some serialization libraries have deserialize methods that take type objects instead of a generic type parameter, and serialize methods that just takes 'object'. If such methods are available I would much prefer such a solution above reflection magic.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know you were able to create generic methods at runtime.
I figured it out and solved my problem. I'm storing the first generic parameter type, return type and the methodinfo itself in an array. When ProcessIncomingRequest is called I create a generic method to my Serializer class with the first parm type and invoke it. The invoke returns an object but the data behind the object still exists and i'm able to serialize it in order to send it back to the client as a final response.